# How to automatically answer call and play prerecorded sound out to the caller and DTMF on Android

Tags: android

Could it be possible now, which we can develop an Android application having the following requirement for its working steps

1. Automatic receive the call, then
2. Play some sound out to the caller, wait for DTMF response, then
3. Record the caller sound (in the case that they permit, by pressing 1 as DTMF response)
4. Callee can play back the recoreded sound later.

Thank for all answers in advance  .....

Comment: I'm looking for an app to handle this. When will this be possible?

Comment: Is it possible now? I want to do these all operations can it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am also making same application...for Automatic  receive call you need to change Source Code of android. I have done it successfully with froyo 2.2. There is method answerCall(Phone phone) in PhoneUtils.java file with that you can automatic receive call.

I am also searching for DTMF....but till now i didn't get anything which can be helpful....for DTMF decoding....

Comment: You would need to change the radio processor's firmware, not android (and needless to say, that is not open source).  In the usual device architecture, the in call audio is simply not available to the application processor which runs linux and android.

Comment: @Nirav:: As u say, for Automatic receive call you need to change Source Code of android. so could you please provide code..how did you do that.??

Answer (score 0):

the first point seems possible. check the state of call if it is ringing state the program can auto attend it for you..you can find more information in this link.
http://www.devlper.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/
http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html

Comment: Please explain how you believe these links answer the first requirement.  It's generally viewed not to be possible, so you'll really need to justify your "answer".